# How to display one to one correspondence?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
 [image]

Here is the book's definition of countable/not countable

[image]

For 2a, I came up with the fact that the set is countably infinite. What helped me reach this conclusion was this section from the book,
[image]

I know that integers greater than 10 would be an infinite set and from that section of the book, I was able to start listing the elements of the set 11, 12, 13, .....
I am having a hard time with showing one to one correspondence though. 
In one of the examples, the author showed one to one correspondence with a function,
[image]

So what I got from that is to show one to one correspondence of two sets, you need a function to map one set to another and then demonstrate that function is both onto and one to one. For 2a, what function should i use to do these steps? Odd made sense to me - 2k +1, but integers greater than 10, what function would you use?

Comment: You made a good start by listing the elements $11,12,13,\ldots.$ Now think how we usually list the integers $1,2,3,\ldots.$ How can you get $1,2,3,\ldots$ from $11,12,13,\ldots$?

Comment: 1,2,3 wouldn't be elements of this set.

Comment: $1,2,3$ are elements of the set you're trying to map _from_ (positive integers). The hint was, those are the elements you want to map $11,12,13$ to. Unfortunately I was thinking the inverse function when I wrote the hint; it might have been more helpful if I had asked how to get $11,12,13$ from $1,2,3$. The answer, as you've seen, is $f(n)=n+10$. (But if a function is one-to-one and onto then so is its inverse function, so forgive me for putting it backwards.)

Comment: Its fine :). I agree. Now that I understand, it's easier to see it when you have a function that maps from {1,2,3} to {11, 12, 13}, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n) = n +10$. It is easy to prove that this function is one to one and onto, and for positive n, it gives the set of all integers greater than 10.

Comment: Oh because it be from z+, which is set of positive integers

Comment: so showing one to one correspondence between positive integers and integers that this function maps to is the idea?

Comment: Yes, that is the general idea.